Parental control lock to stay active above system settings
I have been building my own parental control app for android using android studio and Java. Im working on the lock phone mechanism due to screen time and im having some issues with the lock not being able to display over the system settings. I have had succes with a developer option called "Allow display over System settings". The issue is that i dont know if there is a way to check for that permission, there for if a kid turns the option off the app doesnt know the permission is turned off. Also i want to know if i can maybe add a mechanism that can monitor if someone is trying to exit the lock by going to system settings. something like when settings is opened it kicks the user out and you get put back on the lock. Would that be possible?
App has Device Admin and other needed permissions like "Display over other apps"
In short.
How do i make it that when the lock is active a child cant just enter system settings and bypass the lock with that?
Thank you.
I tried foreground checks, And checks for the developer option permission. none worked so far
